# Is cursor.skip() on indexed keys always faster?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, cursor, query-optimization

I have 2 databases: `slow` and `fast`; each of which was fed with 4096 entries. The `age` key is a unique random integer that was generated with this script:

```
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 4096){
  var randmnum=Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000000)
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randmnum){found=true;break}
  }
  if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randmnum;
}

var i=0;
for (i=0 ; i< arr.length; ++i) {
    db.fast.insert({name:"john doe", email:"once@upon.a.time.com", age:arr[i]});
    db.slow.insert({name:"john doe", email:"once@upon.a.time.com", age:arr[i]});
}
```

Then in mongo shell:

```
> db.createCollection("slow")
> db.createCollection("fast")
> load("theAboveScript.js")
> db.fast.createIndex({"age":1})
```

If I test `find` and `sort` the amount of `work` that has been done on the `fast` db is lower than the `slow` as expected. Moreover the execution time is about 2 times better with the indexed/fast db.

**But** when I do the following:

```
> pageNumber=18;nPerPage=20; db.slow.find().skip(pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage) : 0).limit(nPerPage).explain("executionStats")
> pageNumber=18;nPerPage=20; db.fast.find().skip(pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage) : 0).limit(nPerPage).explain("executionStats")
```

The amount of work is exactly the same and the execution time is similar, even the fast db is a bit slower.

Why [cursor.skip()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) doesn't get any boost if it works on an indexed keys? I would expect the pagination to return the paged data ordered without sorting it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your queries are doing a filter on `age`, so there is no reason to use the index.

If you add a condition on `age`, there will be a difference (even if minimal with so few documents)

```
> pageNumber=18;nPerPage=20; db.slow.find({age:{$gt:200}}).
      skip(pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage) : 0).limit(nPerPage).
      explain("executionStats")

# "executionTimeMillis" : 14,
# "inputStage" : {
#     "stage" : "COLLSCAN",

> pageNumber=18;nPerPage=20; db.fast.find({age:{$gt:200}}).
      skip(pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage) : 0).limit(nPerPage).
      explain("executionStats"

# "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
# "inputStage" : {
#     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
```

Answer (score 1):

As displayed you have index on AGE field, so search by indexed field is faster.

The paging issue comes from fact that, you query is not **covered** which means it need to fetch full document - so index do not come into play in this case.

[Please see this for reference](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/)